# Converting foreach loop to a while loop

Tags: java, loops, foreach, while-loop

So here's the loop I need help converting:

```
public Product findProduct(int id) {

    Product found = null;
    for(Product m : stock){
        if(m.getID() == id){
            found = m;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

It's supposed to search the stock collection (I just started learning so I don't know the terms very well) for a Product object with the same ID field as the int value we entered in the method.
I got idea of a while loop, and I think I somewhat understand it. What I don't get is how I'm supposed to get the value of m.getID(), the ID field in the Product class, in there.
The class is not allowed to have the import.java.util.Iterator

Comment: You need to cast the element when you use iterator.next(). Eg: Product m = (Product) productIterator.next()

Comment: I see no reason to go for a while loop for exactly that reason. Honestly I'd just put a `break;` in after `found = m;` to avoid unnecessary iterations after you've already found what you're looking for.

Comment: ....or just `return m` when you find a match and then `return null` instead of `return found` after the loop has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple and will mean that the Product object returned, provided it is not null, will have the value of `id` accessible via the `getID()` method:

```
public Product findProduct(int id) {

    for(Product m : stock) {
        if(m.getID() == id){
            return m;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Although this works, it isn't any different from what OP already has and doesn't address OP's problem  :/

Comment: What is OP's problem? I am not sure exactly. Can you shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

```
Product found = null;
int counter = 0;
while(counter < stock.size())
{
   if(stock.get(i).getID() == id)
   {
       found = stock.get(i).getID();
       break;
   }
   counter++;
}
```

This will loop through your list using a while loop and quit the loop if an element is found.  break; is used to break out of the loop when the element is found.  Look at the syntax of the while loop and try to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `while` loop, then go over each item using the `get(...)` method:

```
public Product findProduct(int id) {
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < stock.size())
    {
       if(stock.get(counter) != null && stock.get(counter).getID() == id)
           return stock.get(counter);
       counter++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Make sure to do `null` checks when using the `.get(...)` method.

Alternative option with a `for` loop:

```
public Product findProduct(int id) {
    for(int i = 0; i< stock.size(); i++)
       if(stock.get(i) != null && stock.get(i).getID() == id)
           return stock.get(i);

    return null;
}
```

**NOTE**: You may need to use `.equals(...)` here instead of `==` based on how the `Product` class is written.

Then when you call the method:

```
int id = //whatever
Product product = findProduct(id);

int newId;
if(product != null)
    newId = product.getID();//should be same as id
```